# While executing a Test Runner file getting <terminated> TestRunner [junit] C:\Program Files\java\jdk-11\bin\javaw.exe

Tags: test-runner

While executing a Test Runner file getting  TestRunner [junit] C:\Program Files\java\jdk-11\bin\javaw.exe

I tried putting features file into src folder and Run and getting terminated, Even tried putting into Resource folder as well getting same unable to Execute Test Runner file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFKDJ.png)